# SELinux ignoring configuration?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, selinux, vagrant

I'm using Vagrant and VirtualBox to run a CentOS 6.5 VM. In `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` I have set `SELINUX=permissive`. However, everytime I restart the VM, `sudo getenforce` shows SELinux as `Enforcing`. [Here's the Vagrantfile](http://pastebin.com/tN6Rq70m)

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic link to `/etc/selinux/config` was missing. I removed the `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` file and created a symlink to `/etc/selinux/config`. I modified the file again to set selinux to permissive, and rebooted.